# indifferent use of '?' in sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm beating my heading to know why this simple sed

> sed 's/s:?s*/z/' test

test

```
efgs:sgfe
ssssssssss
rsts
abc
```

gives no match
it will work if i omit `?`. I want the first line to match with `efgzgfe`

and see screencap of [image: regexbuddy]. Why it matches there?

Comment: Please post the output as text instead of images. Also as you aren't using the `-r/-E` flag `?` is seen as a literal character

Comment: There are **many** different "flavours" of regular expressions. If you're using an online tool, take care to select the right flavour. I see you're testing with Java regular expressions. That will not be the same as sed regular expressions (which may be called "basic regular expressions").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html), `\?` is a GNU extension.

On a Mac:

```
$ echo 'efgs:sgfe' | sed 's/s:\?s*/z/'
efgs:sgfe
```

On a Raspberry Pi running Debian Linux:

```
$ echo 'efgs:sgfe' | sed 's/s:\?s*/z/'
efgzgfe
```

This works on both:

```
$ echo 'efgs:sgfe' | sed 's/s:\{0,1\}s*/z/'
efgzgfe
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a slash before the ? did it for me and changing the * to a + -- Not sure if you want it to match the third line or not.  If you do, change the '+' back into a '*'.

```
$ cat crap.txt | sed 's/s:\?s+/z/'
efgzgfe
z
rsts
abc
```

Where the data you had is in crap.txt